# Storing Each Iteration of Array after Loop Completion

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I'm very new to Python. I've searched extensively for a solution to my problem, but I'm hitting dead ends left and right.

I've produced a series of arrays using following code:

```
fh = open(short_seq, 'r')
line_counter = 0
pos = [0]
array = [0.0 for x in range(101)]
for line in fh:
    line_counter += 1.0   
    for i in line:
        score = ord(i) - 33.0
        array[pos] += score
        pos += 1
```

After printing inside the loop I get a large series of arrays.

```
[1,2,3,4.....]
[2,3,4,5,6.....]
[3,4,5,6,7,8.....100]
...
```

I'd like to use NumPy to run stats on each column, in the specific alignment that they are printed out in, but once I'm outside of the loop I can only call the sum of entire loop. I tried np.concatenate, but that still left me with the sum of the arrays. If I use NumPy in the loop then I can only run stats on each column, one iteration at a time, rather than the whole series. My next idea was to ad each iteration into a two-dimensional matrix, but I couldn't figure how to keep the alignment.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Here is a sample of my data (each of the four strings are right underneath on another in a text editor). I'm trying to convert a few thousand lines of ascii to numerical values. Each line has to be in an array 100 characters long, and then I need to run stats on each column.

CCCFFFFFHHHHHIJJJJJJIJJJJJJJJIJJJIJJJJJJJIJJIJJGIIIHIIIFGIGFHFGIIIHIHHGEHHFDFFFFFDDDDDBDDDDDDDDEDEEDD
CCCFFFFFHHHHHJJJJJJJJJJIIIJJIGJJJJJJJJJJIJJJJJIJJJJJJIJIJJIJJIJJIJJHGHHHHFFCEFFFEEDAEEEFEEDDDB:ADDDD:
CCCFFFFFHHHHHJIJJJIJJJIJJIJJIIJIIJJJJJJJJJJJJJIIJJJJJJJJJGHHHHFFFFFFEEEEEEEDDDDDEDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD>9<
BCCFFFDFHHHHHJJJJJJJJJJJIIJJJI@HGIIIJJJJJIJJIJIIJJJJJJJJJHHHHHHFFFDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD?BDDDD@CDDDDDBDDDDD

Comment: Try `numpy.sum(array, axis=0)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
array = [0.0 for x in range(101)]
```

is a list.  `array = np.zeros((101,),float)` is an array of the same size.

With `for line in fh:` you get a line, a string.  I expect `for i in line:` to iterate over the characters in that string.  Is that really what you want?

```
for i in line:
    score = ord(i) - 33.0
    array[pos] += score
    pos += 1
```

Usually when people read a text file they want the values of columns separated by spaces or commas, e.g.

```
 123, 345, 344, 233
 343, 342, 343, 343
```

We use `lines.split(',')` to split such as string into substrings. and `float` or `int` to turn those into numbers, eg.

```
 data = [float(substring) for substring in line.split(',')]
```

Show us some of your data file, or a simplified version. It will be easier to help.  A key question is, are the number of 'columns' consistent across lines.

Often when we iterate over the lines of an array, we collect the line values in a list.  If the number of elements in the sublists is consistent we can turn it into a 2d array.

```
 lines = []
 for line in fh:
     data = [float(i) for i in line.split(',')]
     lines.append(data)
 print(lines)
 # A = np.array(lines)
```

===============================

With your sample lines I can do:

```
In [258]: with open('stack38175089.txt') as f:
    lines=f.readlines()
   .....:     

In [259]: [len(l) for l in lines]
Out[259]: [102, 102, 102, 102]

In [260]: data=np.array([[ord(i) for i in l.strip()] for l in lines])

In [261]: data.shape
Out[261]: (4, 101)

In [262]: data
Out[262]: 
array([[67, 67, 67, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 73, 74, 74, 74,
        74, 74, 74, 73, 74, 74, 74, 74, 74, 74, 74, 74, 73, 74, 74, 74, 73,
        74, 74, 74, 74, 74, 74, 74, 73, 74, 74, 73, 74, 74, 71, 73, 73, 73,
        72, 73, 73, 73, 70, 71, 73, 71, 70, 72, 70, 71, 73, 73, 73, 72, 73,
        72, 72, 71, 69, 72, 72, 70, 68, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 68, 68, 68, 68,
        68, 66, 68, 68, 68, 68, 68, 68, 68, 68, 69, 68, 69, 69, 68, 68],
       ...
       [66, 67, 67, 70, 70, 70, 68, 70, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 74, 74, 74, 74,
        74, 74, 74, 74, 74, 74, 74, 73, 73, 74, 74, 74, 73, 64, 72, 71, 73,
        73, 73, 74, 74, 74, 74, 74, 73, 74, 74, 73, 74, 73, 73, 74, 74, 74,
        74, 74, 74, 74, 74, 74, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 70, 70, 70, 68, 68,
        68, 68, 68, 68, 68, 68, 68, 68, 68, 68, 68, 68, 68, 68, 63, 66, 68,
        68, 68, 68, 64, 67, 68, 68, 68, 68, 68, 66, 68, 68, 68, 68, 68]])
```

With a 2d array like this I can easily shift the values (`-33`), and apply  statistical calculations over rows or columns.

I could have read the lines individually and collected the values in a list of lists.  But this sample, and I suspect your whole file, is small enough to use `readlines`.

Comment: Thank you for the response. The raw data (ascii characters) is consistent across the lines in the file, however, when I convert the characters and start to populate the array in a loop it's skewed, but only in the beginning.

Comment: I loaded your sample into a 2d array.